# ubuntu: kept old menu.lst, think it is the source of problems

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, grub, kernel

I recently upgraded to karmic, and clicked to keep my old menu.lst (to keep my windows XP boot info)... but now I'm not using the right kernel.  Is there a way to have it give me the correct up to date menu.lst file again which I can manually merge into my old file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you chose to go with Grub 2 (if you have a ton of files including 'grub.cfg'  /boot/grub, you're using grub 2). Grub2 completely ignores the menu.lst file, instead using a generated grub.cfg created using templates in /etc/grub.d and settings in /etc/default/grub. There's a good writeup on the [Ubuntu Forums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275). So it shouldn't be a problem with your menu.lst at all.

Do you see grub at all when you boot up? Do you have a custom kernel that maybe grub doesn't know about yet? Try running update-grub as root and see if that helps.

Comment: Actually, I was using just grub.  Upgrading to grub2 grabbed my newest kernel information though, which is what I wanted, so booting works much better now. Thanks